# Stylus Pen integrated into Digital Form?

Tags: php, android, forms, stylus-pen

Background:
I very recently learned some basic php (and therefore am quite naive as to what is possible or not) to transform the paper forms to forms on our website.  Our employees are not very tech savy and have a hard time typing it in.  We tried using the microphone function to fill in the boxes of the forms, but half the time that leads to very confusing submissions.  The employees all have Galaxy Note Phablets with a stylus pen.

Question:
Is there any way to integrate a writing box for the pen that saves as a jpg/png and into a folder on the website?  I have been able to do this with pictures taken by the camera through   Is there a way to do similar other than writing on a piece of paper and uploading a picture of that?  Would the best way to make the forms digital be by writing an Android app?

These are fairly simple log forms.  Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Without going into details, I am  pretty sure this is doable with jQuery. By searching Google quickly I found Sketch.js, you might be interested in it.

Comment: Fantastic! Time to try and pick up a few basics of jQuery and Javascript.  Hope it works :)

Comment: I hope it will point you in the right direction! :)

Comment: Update in case anyone looks for the same thing:  I will still be using this tactic for another feature, but one of our employees found a built-in function on the Samsung Galaxy Note.  By holding the key that is by default microphone, one can switch the setting to using the pen.  It then converts writing into text with fantastic accuracy.